# Произношение слова "нечто"

Tags: орфоэпия

Вроде Ч в словах, производных от *что,* читается как Ш во всех словах кроме *нечто.* Однако где-то месяц назад я услышать, как женщина, позвонившая на Эхо, произнесла *не**ш**то*. Это однозначно неправильно или допустимо?

Уточню, что там было именно слово *нечто* (что-то), а не вопросительное слово *нешто* (которое и пишется через Ш).

Comment: Кроме "нешто", есть славное "пошто": http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x

Comment: Точно)*********

Comment: Угу. А с ним, сердешным, сердечная болезнь приключилась...

Comment: Точно! И я замечал эту разницу в произношении в зависимости от смысла в этих словах.

Comment: За что Вы против-то проголосовали?!

Comment: Тёма, коммент пришёл ко мне. Так это не я  всех минусую, а б/у-с. У меня было два плюса за ответ - куда пропали?

Comment: Какой такой б/у-с?!)

Comment: Твой любимец. Он ещё и помощь позвал. Война объявлена мне, Сержу и Сергею. Нас слишком мало, чтобы устроить достойное противостояние. А ты под горячую руку попал. За неразборчивость в любовях.

Comment: Почему прям любимец! Я видел, что Вы поставили минус, у Вас -2 по этому вопросу... (

Comment: Я вчера поставила плюс, а минусы мои - за снятые плюсы и полезность ответа. Зачем я тебя буду минусить? Мы с тобой всегда в ладу сосуществовали.

Comment: А почему Вы сняли плюс, не пойму? Я рад, что по-прежнему всё в порядке, а то как-то засомневался, мало ли что.)

Comment: Тёмочка, спасибо. Я тебе скрины по почте пришлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однозначно недопустимо.

У нас в редакции работала таганрожка, усиленно штурмующая московский говор. Так у неё произносилось *плитошно-облицовошный.* Народ был в улёте.

С незначительными вариациями приводится список слов с -чн-, которые -шн-, а про "нечто" - безоговорочно: исключение из всех форм, образованных от "что".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если произношение местоимения "нечто" сомнений не вызывает, то некоторые из -чн- мною, например, не соблюдаются: "праче**ч**ная". (А было бы строго -шн-, анекдот с министерством культуры, отвечающим в рифму, не состоялся бы...)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моло**шн**ый поросёнок?! Получи, фашист, гранату!

---

К комментариям.

Современный универсальный словарь русского языка (2013):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Устарело, но - допустимо.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! Только я не пойму, почему там нету слов *достато[шн]ый* и *симпати[шн]ый.* Допустим, *симпатичный* говорят через Ш **только** в шутку, хотя я так не думал, но разве неправильно говорить *достато[шн]ый?*

Comment: Было - сплыло. http://pda.gramota.ru/?action=buro&s=236600#/page/1 *...Так, изменилась, например, норма произношения «шн» на месте орфографического «чн»: по старой московской норме правильно — скушно, булошная, достатошно, перешница...* http://slovari21.ru/analytics/910

Comment: Хорошая статеечка *Произношение орфографического сочетания чн*: http://orfoslova.dljatebja.ru/Vvedenie/Proiznoshenie_orfograficheskogo_sochetanija_chn.html